# retrieving nonprimitive types in an assembly with .NET Reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection

Is there any class or specific method for getting non-primitive types in an assembly? FieldInfo.Gettype() will do for primtive types  but what about non-primitive types?

Answer (score 3):

It's not at all clear what you mean - and "FieldInfo.GetType works for primitive types" is an odd starting point, as if you call `GetType()` on a `FieldInfo` reference, you'll always get a type derived from `FieldInfo`... whereas if you use [`FieldInfo.FieldType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.fieldtype.aspx), that will access the type of the field.

But yes, you can definitely get at the types within an assembly, e.g. with [`Assembly.GetType(string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y0cd10tb.aspx) to get one particular type, or [`Assembly.GetTypes()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.gettypes.aspx) to get *all* the types.

If you could tell us more about what you're trying to achieve and give us a code sample which shows what information you have and what you're trying to get, that would help us to help you more.

Comment: sorry, but could u plz take a look here to see exactly what I mean?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vbgeneral/thread/066fdb47-ae2f-4741-b498-13562926868a

Comment: @FidEliO: Even there your question is unclear. There's a *wall* of code, and I'm sure most of it is irrelevant to your aims. Please try to come up with a *short but complete* example of what you're trying to do. I have to say that using reflection like this should be a last option anyway... do you really have no alternative?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what actually is your question but guess you are looking for `typeof(Type)`.

Comment: check here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269864/retrieving-data-adapter-select-command-parameters-in-an-assembly-via-another-data

Comment: @FidEliO: That question doesn't actually make it much clearer - especially as it's got one *enormous* line of code which is basically unreadable in its current form.

Comment: Over eleven thousand characters in one method call.  Impressive.

Answer (score 0):

```
AssemblyInstance.GetTypes().Where(x => !x.IsPrimitive)
```

if you are looking for the NonPrimitive fields in a type:

```
TypeInstance.GetFields().Where(x => !x.FieldType.IsPrimitive)
```